# How to deploy apigee proxies with node target servers that use node modules that are not pre-installed?

Tags: node.js, apigee

This question is about deploying proxies with node target servers that use node modules that are not pre-installed. We use apigee edge running on-premises.

The node target servers runs fine locally.

The question is simple: How do I deploy such proxies with node target servers to apigee edge on-premises?

### Attempt 1

I have tried packaging the proxy into a zip-file as usual and uploaded it in the web browser using the 'import into new revision' feature. It has worked fine for simpler proxies (that only use pre-installed node modules). All dependencies are listed in the packages.json file. When the proxy is deployed, every api call results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 148

{"fault":{"faultstring":"Script node executed prematurely: Script exited with code 0","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.runtime.ScriptExitedError"}}}
```

### Attempt 2

I've also tried to install the modules locally using 'npm install' and then include the modules in the zip. However, in this case there is a red error message the import failed. When I reload the api proxy page in the web browser it seems like the package was actually uploaded, and the box that show loading progress goes to more than 2000%. However, when the loading has completed, it is not possible to deploy it (a standard unspecific error message is displayed).

### Attempt 3

Finally I have also tried the apigeetool using the syntax at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/adding-nodejs-existing-api-proxy (I did change the url in the python source code to our on-premises server). Before running the tool, the modules are installed using 'npm install'. The result is this error message:

> Importing new application %PROXYNAME%
>
> /v1/organizations/%ORGANIZATION%/apis?action=import&name=%PROXYNAME%
>
> Import failed to
>
> /v1/organizations/%ORGANIZATION%/apis?action=import&name=%PROXYNAME%
>
> with status 404: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Classification failed for
>
> host %IP%:%PORT%","detail":{"code":"CLASSIFICATION_FAILED"}}}

Comment: Hi Joakim, some modules are not at all supported in Apigee Edge. Here is a list http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/understanding-edge-support-nodejs-modules  Which module are you trying?

Comment: Also, CLASSIFICATION_FAILED is Apigee Edge's equivalent of a 404. It appears that you may simply have the wrong URL for the server.

Comment: @SantanuDey: Right now I use wcf.js and xml2js. None of those are displayed in the page you linked to.

Comment: @ap-andrew, do you happen to know if the API that apigeetool tries to use isn't available on-premises?

Comment: Joakim, the APIs are consistent between the cloud and the on-prem version, so yes, that API is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using OSX or a flavour of *nix:

1. Create a folder on your local machine to contain your Node script (e.g. `/Development/myNodeProxy/`). Place your script there. (e.g. `server.js`).
2. Open Terminal and `cd` to your script folder (`/Development/myNodeProxy/`).
3. Use `npm` to install the modules you need (type `npm install {modulename}` without the global `-g` switch). **Caveat**: Edge doesn't play nice with conflicting versions of [`Express`](http://expressjs.com/), so you will need to `npm remove express` before deploying. You may need to remove other the modules that are [preinstalled on Edge](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/understanding-edge-support-nodejs-modules) too if you end up getting errors (like `errno 32 broken pipe`).
4. From the same directory, run the following command:

   `apigeetool deploynodeapp -n {name-of-your-proxy} -o {org} -e {environment} -b {proxy-basepath} -d ./ -m server.js -u {your-email-address/username} -p {password}`

Comment: doesn't this try to deploy to the cloud version of apigee? We run apigee edge on-premises.

Comment: Ah, yes it does. I'll see what I can find out for you.